# Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing in Ajax Request

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-analytics

I have the following code which sends data to Google Analytics. But I am getting "Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing" in Ajax response.

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "https://www.google-analytics.com/collect",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "jso",
            crossDomain: true,
            data: JSON.stringify({tid: "UA-XXXXXX-1", v: 1, cid: "<?php echo uniqid(); ?>",t: "pageview", dt: "HomeNewPage",dh: "EXAMPLE.com",dp:"newHome"}),
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("success");
            },
            error: function (text) {
                respond(messageInternalError);
            }
    });
```

Can anyone guide me? I have looked in various sources but couldn't get proper result.

Comment: Inspect in chrome and see if your ajax request has this header `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'`.

Comment: @lakshay The header must be set in the response, not in the request.

Comment: why negative vote. I have tried and I do not get this so I am asking.

Comment: read about CORS. if your URL is correct, you won't be able to call it in your page, browser policy will not allow it.